# Error when returning a string from a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I made a function that converts an image to Base64 so I can upload it to my database:

```
export function converToBase64(e): string {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  reader.onload = () => {
    console.log(reader.result);
    return reader.result;
  };
  reader.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log("Error", error);
  };
}
```

I added console.log before the return to make sure the reader.result has the image in Base64 then I called the function here:

```
const handleImage = (e) => {
    project.image = converToBase64(e);
    console.log(project.image);
  };
```

Now it shows in my console that project.image is undefined while the reader.result that I console logged before the return is showing the image in Base64, so the function converToBase64 is returning undefined object and I don't know why.

I also noticed that in my console the console.log(project.image) is executed before the console.log in the converToBase64 function, could that be why and how do I fix it?

Comment: You **aren't** returning a string. You have two event handlers, and one of them returns a string, but your function doesn't. See the linked question's answers for how to deal with it.

Comment: You **aren't** returning a string. You aren't returning **anything**, `converToBase64` has no `return` statement. (`reader.onload` has a `return` statement, but that's a different function). I'm surprised the TypeScript compiler isn't throwing a build time error because the `: string` condition isn't met.

Comment: @Quentin - Jinx!

Comment: oh so thats whats happening, ok got it thanks